# Don't know how to start combinatorics problems

Tags: combinatorics

I recently started "A Walk Through Combinatorics" I am an undergraduate math major who is about to wrap up Calculus 2 and am about halfway through "A Book of Proof." I figured this would be a great time to explore an area of math that seemed really cool and interesting to me, combinatorics. However, I have run into a problem, when I get to the exercises in section 1 I have no idea where to start a majority of these problems. I felt like I understood what was going on in the examples and the material presented made sense but once I reach the exercises I don't know what to do or even how to begin to tackle the exercises. Any advice?

Comment: Is it possible to find a book oriented towards Combinatorics that is easier and includes many, many exercises?  Then, you could use the easier book as a stepping stone to the book that you are currently using.  Extending this idea, you could (for example) search MathSE for questions tagged reference-request or book-recommendations, or something like that, that contain also contain the word "Combinatorics".  ...see next comment

Comment: When you see various author titles, such as <The Title>, <The Author>, then you could google on (for example) "The Title The Author pdf".  If the book is available online, as a pdf, then you could try studying chapter 1 of the pdf and doing its exercises to see if you can solve them.  If so, you can consider buying the book.  Alternatively, you could examine Amazon Book reviews of relevant titles.  Personally, I think that finding the right book for you, which is often different from what is the right book for others, makes all the difference.

Comment: Have you talked with the prof or TA?

Comment: There is no professor or TA just me learning on my own for this one

Comment: Could you tell us what you have already studied in combinatorics?

Comment: A couple of books that I find easier than "A Walk Through Combinatorics": "Mathematics of Choice", Niven; "Applied Combinatorics", Tucker.  Maybe one of those will work for you.

Comment: Combinatorics can be a bit mind-boggling and hard to visualize at first sight, so maybe start with the easiest problems, emulate the examples in the book, and master the basics before moving on to more complex topics.

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply I was away from home and then had an exam to take. To answer N.F. Taussig, my only experience with combinatorics is what you may find in an intro-proofing book so some basic questions about principles of counting, binomial coefficient, k permutations, inclusion-exclusion, binomial theorem, and counting multisets.